# Can I echo to host's local /dev/tty1 with SSH?

Tags: ssh, raspbian, tty

I am logged in on a Linux machine. I want to send a message (to a physical screen of the host I'm calling) to be displayed in terminal. Like... chatting with whoever is using this computer at the moment. But going simple `ssh pi@raspberrypi echo 'Hi!' > /dev/tty1` gives me "there is no such file or a directory" on `/dev/tty1`. Doing the same command locally works, it finds `tty1`. Logging as root doesn't help. I've also found this command (but it's too complicated for me to understand):

```
kill -s SIGINT `ps -ft pts/2 | grep pts/2 | cut -d ' ' -f 5`
```

It prompts `error: TTY could not be found`. Is what I want possible?

Comment: Your command echoes to the local `/dev/tty1`, not the remote. What is your intention? What about trying to use the TTY that you're connected to? `/dev/tty`. If you want to do this remotely, use `ssh -t user@host 'echo hello >/dev/tty'`, although I must confess I don't quite see the point.  Why did you include that last command pipeline? In what way is that relevant to your question?

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't want remote tty, I want to see the echo output on the screen connected to the host I'm calling. Like... writing messages to person using it.

Comment: @Kusalananda it was an accepted answer to question similar to mine, sth about using existing process to output into tty. Your suggestion gives me ssh error "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal" but was it suppose to achieve what I wanted? Writing remotely on host's local screen?

Comment: Have you tried using the `write` command, which is used for writing on other user's terminals? You can't write directly to someone else's TTY, because you don't have the right permissions.